# send a C# global variable's value to a cshtml file

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a C# class, and inside this class I have a string variable (global) whose value is needed in a cshtml file. What can I do to retrieve it?
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What's a global variable in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
namespace Site.Controllers 
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public static String title = "foobar";
    }
}
```

Then you can access it in cshtml files like this:

```
<div>@Site.Controllers.Globals.title</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an instance variable, you can pass it down as part of the model.  If it is a static variable, then you can explicitly access it the same way you would use any other variable.